# Json layer on folium map is missing, but there are no errors

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am trying to overlay a Voronoi diagram over a folium web map. I am creating the voronoi map with SciPy and then converting it to Json. When I generate the map, the entire map is there except for the Voronoi layer, but the layer does show up in Layer Control.

I'm guessing that the error is somewhere in how the Json file is being created. I've been searching but without an error, I haven't been able to find anything

Folium map generation

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[43.521, -120.587],
zoom_start = 7.45,
tiles = 'Mapbox Bright')

tooltip = 'Click for detailed information'

for point in range(len(locationList)):
    folium.Marker(locationList[point], popup = labels[point], icon = folium.Icon(color = colors[point]), parse_html=True).add_to(m)

m.save('index.html')
```

Voronoi diagram generation

```py
### Create volonai map
points = np.array(df[["geo_long","geo_lat"]].values.tolist()) # Create points, each point is a hospital

vor = Voronoi(points) #Create voronoi object 

voronoi_plot_2d(vor) # Create voronoi plot object
```

Conversion to Json

```py
vorJSON = open('libVor.json', 'w')

point_voronoi_list = []
feature_list = []
for region in range(len(vor.regions)-1):    
    vertex_list = []
    for x in vor.regions[region]:
        if x == -1:
            break;
        else:
            vertex = vor.vertices[x]
            vertex = (vertex[1], vertex[0])
        vertex_list.append(vertex)
    polygon = Polygon([vertex_list])
    feature = Feature(geometry=polygon, properties={})
    feature_list.append(feature)


feature_collection = FeatureCollection(feature_list)
print (feature_collection, file=vorJSON)
vorJSON.close()
```

Adding layer to the map

```py
vorGeoJson = json.load(open('libVor.json'))

folium.GeoJson(vorGeoJson, 
                name = 'geojson'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

print(m)

m.save(outfile='libVor.html')
```

My goal is to get the polygons to overlay on the web map

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue when trying to plot geoJSON files on my folium map. I figured out my issue was the absence of/wrong coordinate system.

Since I was converting my data from shapefile to geoJSON I used QGIS to project the data into right coordinate system (I believe that EPSG:4326 - WGS84 usually works).